# Eclipse extension point for Open Resource/Open Type dialogs

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

Is there an extension point where I can customize the search behavior of these dialog boxes?

Or am I better off making an extensions that just overrides those hotkeys with dialog boxes that subclass [FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog.java.htm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These dialogs don't support customization.

Open Resource is `OpenResourceDialog` (an internal class) derived from `FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog`.

Open Type is `OpenTypeSelectionDialog` (again internal) derived from another internal class `FilteredTypesSelectionDialog` which in turn is derived from `FilteredItemsSelectionDialog`.

Comment: So if I want to do minor tweaks to OpenResourceDialog I should just copy that class into my plugin? (I can't find a way to subclass an internal eclipse class).

Comment: Subclassing internal classes is against the API rules of engagement. Yes, you could copy class to make changes - but you would have to use a new menu item to access dialog.